# REGEXP_SUBSTR issue in oracle SE 12.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My query in *Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production*

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('%DC.DATA%','[\.][A-z0-9_]+') FROM DUAL
```

returns wrong result '.DATA%' while the same query in *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production* return right result '.DATA'.
Has anyone faced such issue ?

Comment: Haven't seen it. Are you a paying customer (meaning: do you have access to Oracle support)? If you are, you can log in to Oracle support to check for known bugs. (I am not a paying customer, so I can't do it for you.) Other than that, did you try anything to get to the bottom of this? For example, do you still get the wrong result if you remove the underscore? What if you use `\w` instead of `[A-z0-9_]`? Do you still get the wrong result if you have another non-word character at the end, like `#` or `&`, instead of `%`? Etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to Oracle support as well. Forgotten to mention, the same problem with other noh-word character, e.g. #, ^,$ . Tried \w instead of [A-z0-9_] according your suggestion, got equal right results in both editions

Comment: Removing underscore did not help as well

Comment: Using `A-z` in a bracketed expression, like you are, is probably wrong anyway. In the ASCII character set, there are characters other than letters between A and z; A to Z are one sequence, then the next characters are [ then \ then ] and a few more (but not %), and only after that, a to z. It's possible that your SE installation has a different character set, and/or different NLS settings (NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP). You may want to run `select * from v$nls_parameters`  and add that to your post, we may get some clues from that. In any case, best to use `\w` or similar to be safe.

Comment: Many thanks for your hints and your time. NLS_SORTs turned out to be different in SE and EE. Sure \w instead of A-z is more correct, thanks again